# Базы данных

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Всем привет!

Есть два не зависимых сайта, две базы Mysql. Есть кнопка перехода на поддомен. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать, чтобы вводя логин и пароль на первом сайте, переходило на второй сайт, но при условии, если логин и пароль правильные, и имеются в базе данных №2. Если логин и пароль введен не правильно, то никакого перехода на поддомен не должно происходить. Как это можно реализовать?

Заранее благодарен.

Юрий

Comment: В чем проблема сделать редирект с сайта 2 на сайт 1?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы реализовал это посредством ajax'a. Послал данные в обработчик, если пришел положительный ответ, то перенаправил бы. Мне так кажется, что Вы пишите фэйковый одностраничник, к примеру соц. сети Вконтакте, юзер вводит логин и пароль и его перебрасывает на официальный сайт с логином уже.

> http://login.vk.com/?act=login&email=$mail&pass=$pass

Вот пример перенаправления. Но Вы уточнили, что это поддомен, так что, как я уже писал - юзайте ajax

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Но кажется Вам не правильно. Есть полноценные рабочие сайты и никаких одностраничных фэйков ))
Буду пробовать через ajax.
Еще раз спасибо за ответ.